# Loading a dll that depends on other dll ..?

Tags: windows, dll

What happens when I load some dll at run-time (let's call it Lib1.dll) but Lib1.dll also depends on Lib2.dll but Lib2.dll is not there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends (sorry).  If the DLL in question is statically linked to the missing DLL, then the LoadLibrary call will fail with error 126 (ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND). If, however, the DLL attempts to load the missing DLL dynamically (e.g., with LoadLibrary), then the original LoadLibrary call may succeed.  The behavior may also change for [delay loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) libraries.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a missing dependency, the program won't run: an exception/error will be thrown when an access to the DLL is attempted.

Answer (score 0):

you will get a I/O error when it tries to use something from that dll. it will say it cant load it

Comment: The error/exception happens immediately at load time of the DLL, not when it is used.

Comment: depends how its been used. If you do lazy loading it may load and use at the same time